# Should Raku run MAIN if the file is required?

Tags: raku, modulino

Here's a short Raku program that declare a [MAIN](https://docs.raku.org/routine/MAIN.html) subroutine. I should only see output if I execute the program directly:

```
$ cat main.rakumod
sub MAIN { say "Called as a program!" }
```

And I see output when I execute the program directly:

```
$ raku main.rakumod
Called as a program!
```

If I load it as a module, I see no output:

```
$ raku -I. -Mmain -e "say 'Hey'"
Hey
```

Same if I `use` it from inside the program, I see no output:

```
$ raku -I. -e 'use main'
```

But, if I use `require`, I get output:

```
$ raku -I. -e 'require <main.rakumod>'
Called as a program!
```

[Synopsis 06](https://design.raku.org/S06.html#Declaring_a_MAIN_subroutine) literally says *the compilation unit was directly invoked rather than by being required*. Is there something else going on because `require` works at runtime (although S06 doesn't exclude that)?

I get the same behaviour with Rakudo Star 2016.07 and 2016.10.

Comment: does it make a difference if you omit the file extension?

Comment: @Christoph: without the file extension for require, it doesn't find the file.

Comment: makes sense - the proper syntax for what I had in mind is `require ::('main')`

Answer (score 4):

First, let's take a look at how `require` is supposed to behave:

According to the (non-authorative) [design documents](https://design.raku.org/S11.html#Runtime_Importation),

> Alternately, a filename may be mentioned directly, which installs a package that is effectively anonymous to the current lexical scope, and may only be accessed by whatever global names the module installs:

and

> Only explicitly mentioned names may be so imported. In order to protect the run-time sanctity of the lexical pad, it may not be modified by `require`.

In combination with [S06](https://design.raku.org/S06.html#Declaring_a_MAIN_subroutine)'s

> This call is performed if and only if:
>
> a) the compilation unit was directly invoked rather than by being required by another compilation unit [...]

it is my understanding that a sub `MAIN` not explicitly imported into the mainline lexical scope should not be run.

Sadly, the [user documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#require) is quiet on the case of runtime importation via file name, and a quick glance at the (authorative) [test suite](https://github.com/raku/roast) (in particular [S11-modules/require.t](https://github.com/raku/roast/blob/master/S11-modules/require.t)) did not yield an answer either, though I just might have missed it.

Now, let's take a look at how Rakudo behaves:

As expected, runtime importation via static or dynamic module name

```
require main;
```

or

```
require ::('main');
```

will not run `MAIN` unless it is both declared `is export` and explicitly imported, ie

```
require main <&MAIN>;
```

and

```
require ::('main') <&MAIN>;
```

respectively.

Importation via file name however

```
require 'main.rakumod';
```

will immediately run `MAIN`.

In fact, if you do a proper import via

```
require 'main.rakumod' <&MAIN>;
```

the sub will be executed twice: Once when loading the compilation unit, and a second time when the runtime does its job looking and running any `MAIN` sub in the mainline scope.

Rakudo apparently treats a `require` with file name argument more or less like `EVALFILE` and executes its mainline, including any sub `MAIN` it encounters.

That's *not* what I would have expected and possibly just a bug.

Comment: This is some good info, and I also wouldn't expect MAIN to run unless it's in the mainline code. That is, actually in the file originally run. If it comes from any other file, it shouldn't run. That includes EVALFILE.

Comment: @briandfoy: agreed, tentatively: if `EVALFILE` no longer executes `MAIN`, there probably should be an alternative that does (a named parameter to `EVALFILE`? a new sub `RUNFILE`? a sh-style `SOURCEFILE`? ...)

Comment: Yeah, tricky. But, if it's documented that it goes one way or the other I can work with that even if it does something different. But, maybe you could read a file into a string and eval that string.